# Why are we using (html, body) is the below code why not only body?

Tags: html, css

How is "," a CSS combinator and can we use space instead for Descendant Selector?

```
html, body{
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      background-color: hsl(204, 43%, 93%);
      font-family: Karla, sans-serif;
      font-size: 1rem;
      font-weight: 400;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
```

Comment: only the person who wrote the code can answer you. The height:100% is the relevant one that need you to use `html,body`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case I would suggest you don't apply styling to the html selector since the <html> tag serves as a container for the entire page, its the root node.

On to your question: by comma separating selectors, you are telling CSS that you want the styling to apply to both selectors.

You can even chain ".class" selectors, "element.class" selectors, and pseudo-class selectors such as .button:hover (if you've added "class=button" to the <button> html tag's attributes).

Also, yes, in CSS you can chain multiple selectors with spaces if they are .class selectors.

Here is (probably a crummy) example:

The Html

```
<table class="table">
  <tr class="row">
    <th class="header"> Heading 1 </th>
    <th class="header"> Heading 2 </th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row">
    <td class="cell">Cell 1</td>
    <td class="cell">Cell 2</td>
</table>
```

The CSS

```
.table {
/* Styling for the table container */
}

.table .row {
/* Styling for rows */
}

.table .row .header {
/* Styling for column titles */
}

.table .row .cell {
/* Styling for table cells */
}

.table .row .cell:hover {
/* Styling for cells on hover (pseudo-class) */
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also try (temporarily just to see if it works) to make it work without loading an external css file by just adding the  element with the css code inside like so, make sure to place it AFTER the  and BEFORE the ! AND as Mick said, probably leave the html targeting:

```
<style>
    body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        background-color: hsl(204, 43%, 93%);
        font-family: Karla, sans-serif;
        font-size: 1rem;
        font-weight: 400;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
</style>
```

If that works then try to include the external css file